# jQuery two functions for select attribute onchange having different attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got 1 select attribute
I got something to trigger for the select

first:

```
<select id="select-room" data-room="inhouse"></select>
```

second:

```
<select id="select-room" data-room="ar_account"></select>
```

I have already done this the thing is when I make a function for this thing it wont work like:

```
 $('#select-room').on('change','[data-room="inhouse"]', this.Change1);
 $('#select-room').on('change','[data-room="ar_account"]', this.Change2);
```

the thing is these 2 functions wont work

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle which shows it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be same `id` in one DOM. Because when you do so, the DOM will search for the id (here "select-room") from the top and it will consider the first one comes across.

So this is a bad idea to use the same id multiple times. Use `class` instead.

```
<select class="select-room" data-room="inhouse"></select>
<select class="select-room" data-room="ar_account"></select>

$('.select-room[data-room="inhouse"]').on('change', this.Change1);
$('.select-room[data-room="ar_account"]').on('change', this.Change2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not use same id for multiple elements, selector will only target first matched element, I have changed it to class in the code. If the issue is that data-room is changing for element, you can use event delegation here and attach event to document instead or to some parent element, like this:

```
<select class="select-room" data-room="inhouse"></select>
<select class="select-room" data-room="ar_account"></select>

$(document).on('change', '.select-room[data-room="inhouse"]', this.Change1);
$(document).on('change', '.select-room[data-room="ar_account"]', this.Change2);
```

Comment: I think he means he has one select and the data-room attribute is changing.  Based on the attribute he wants a different event to fire.

Comment: @norlando oh now I understand, thanks for pointing, code updated.